# WP Как убрать из URL кастомного типа записи слаг типа этой записи?

Tags: php, wordpress

Есть в Wordpress кастомный тип записи задаваемый в function.php таким кодом

```
/*
 *  Тип записей для производителей Тип записи Game
 */

function create_games_posttype() {
    $labels = array(
        'name' => _x( 'Games', 'Тип записей Games', 'mysite' ),
        'singular_name' => _x( 'Game', 'Тип записей game', 'mysite' ),
        'menu_name' => __( 'Games', 'mysite' ),
        'all_items' => __( 'Все игры', 'mysite' ),
        'view_item' => __( 'Обзор игры', 'mysite' ),
        'add_new_item' => __( 'Добавить новую игру', 'mysite' ),
        'add_new' => __( 'Добавить новую игру', 'mysite' ),
        'edit_item' => __( 'Редактировать игру', 'mysite' ),
        'update_item' => __( 'Обновить игру', 'mysite' ),
        'search_items' => __( 'Искать игру', 'mysite' ),
        'not_found' => __( 'Не найдено', 'mysite' ),
        'not_found_in_trash' => __( 'Не найдено в корзине', 'mysite' ),
    );

    $args = array(
        'label' => __( 'games', 'mysite' ),
        'description' => __( 'Каталог игр', 'mysite' ),
        'labels' => $labels,
        'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'excerpt', 'thumbnail', 'comments', 'revisions', 'custom-fields', 'post-formats' ),
        'taxonomies' => array('vendors', 'game-types', 'post_tag'),
        'hierarchical' => true,
        'public' => true,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'show_in_menu' => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus' => true,
        'show_in_admin_bar' => true,
        'menu_position' => 5,
        'can_export' => true,
        'has_archive' => true,
     

        'rewrite'   => array(
            'slug' => '',   // тип поста и сама таксономия
           'with_front' => false
        ),
        'exclude_from_search' => false,
        'publicly_queryable' => true,
        'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-buddicons-activity',
        'capability_type' => 'post',
    );

    register_post_type( 'games', $args );
}
add_action( 'init', 'create_games_posttype', 0 );
```

на выходе, при вот таком формировании ЧПУ в настройках WP
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я получаю такой путь -

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вопрос - как убрать из кастомного типа записи вот эту "подрубрику" `/games`  Пробовал присвоить значение `'rewrite' => false,`  Но тогда URL приобретает вид
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
А мне необходимо просто без данного элемента. Что б просто было `http://mysite.loc/test-custom-post/`

Comment: А если будет запись с слагом "test-custom-post", то как двидок должен понять что вывести? Не надо этого хотеть.

Comment: Какая альтернатива, если мне для обычных постов нужен один шаблон, а для постов типа games другой шаблон ? Каждому присваивать шаблон через Template Name: ...?  Если этих постов очень много

Comment: Шаблон к урлу не имеет никакого отношения.

Comment: Моя задача отделить визуально простые посты от постов типа games c сохранением человеко понятных урлов, как можно меньшей длинны вложенности. Есть разумные предложения по решению ?

Comment: Сделать шаблон типа контента. Но это уже другой вопрос.

Comment: Не надо этого делать

Comment: https://www.kobzarev.com/wordpress/woocommerce-kill-performance/

Comment: Спасибо конечно, но я тогда не улавливаю какой смысл тогда в принципе от кастомного типа поста, если его нельзя (не рекомендуют) выводить как отдельную сущность? Есть костомная  таксономия (рубрика) которая регистрируется через 'register_taxonomy', тут вроде всё понятно, а зачем нужно что-то по типу 'post'/'page' но при этом его нельзя привязывать без рубрики? Что-то тут не то.